# Two hermitian matrices that commute?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out whether the following implication is correct or not:

> If $B$ is Hermitian and $A$ is Hermitian positive definite, then $A$ and $B$ commute.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it is a claim, then it shouldn't be a question...

Comment: Have you tried this for any pairs of matrices?  Just make up some $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrix and some positive definite $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrix, and see whether they commute.

Comment: Try a couple examples with $A$ diagonal and $B$ non-diagonal.

Comment: And after you have tried some examples, if you then know what's up, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "if $AB$ is Hermitian ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the following example, we can show that $A$ and $B$ don't necessarily commute:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0\\ 
0 &2 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let $
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1+i \\ 
 1-i& 4
\end{bmatrix}$

$A$ is hermitian positive definite, and $B$ is hermitian. Note that: $$AB=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1+i \\ 
 2-2i& 4
\end{bmatrix}\neq BA=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2+2i \\ 
1-i & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$